# "An error occurred while updating some of the page" Status 500 Xpages Save

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have an Xpage consisting of a few custom controls - application layout, content (dojo_data grid), and a custom control that shows some user data, which the user can change.

Everything works fine in the 9 client, but on the web I get the following error message:[image]

The log shows this:

CLFAD0134E: Exception processing XPage request

I have a save button in the custom control with the user data, which has SSJS:

```
var usrNme = session.getCommonUserName();
var v:NotesView = database.getView("(employeesByFullName)");
var doc:NotesDocument = v.getDocumentByKey(usrNme);

var tmpOfficePhone = employee.getItemValueString("HR_OfficePhone")
doc.replaceItemValue("HR_OfficePhone",tmpOfficePhone);

var tmpCellPhone = employee.getItemValueString("HR_CellPhone")
doc.replaceItemValue("HR_CellPhone",tmpCellPhone);

var tmpExtension = employee.getItemValueString("HR_Extension")
doc.replaceItemValue("HR_Extension",tmpExtension);

var tmpDirectDial = employee.getItemValueString("HR_DirectDial")
doc.replaceItemValue("HR_DirectDial",tmpDirectDial);

var tmpPersonalEmail = employee.getItemValueString("HR_PersonalEmail")
doc.replaceItemValue("HR_PersonalEmail",tmpPersonalEmail);

doc.save();

var x= "alert('Your changes have been saved.')";
view.postScript(x);
```

I have partial update selected, and whatever I pick to update I still get the error, just with slightly different verbiage. Example: I put everything in a panel and do a partial update on the panel, and I get the error for the panel.

It ALWAYS works in the client, but never works in a web browser.

Can anyone tell me what is going on?

Comment: Check your XPages logs on the server under the data\IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT folder for further details.

Comment: Bryan, I can highly recommend that you install XPages Log File Reader as it gives you very easy access to those log files: http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages+Log+File+Reader

Answer (score 1):

You want to remodel your application and use data binding instead of going after the document and controls manually. You might want to start with [a tutorial](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/tutorial-intro-to-xpages.htm), but here is the gist of it:

1. Add a DominoDocument data source to your page
2. Specify the form of your documents (that's actually only needed for convenience in Designer and for the case where you need/want to use `.computeWithForm`
3. Design your form by binding your various controls to the DominoDocument data source. By default that binds it to a new empty document. Usually that's a good choice (see below)

Now, to actually edit an existing document with that XPage, do one of the following:

- Open the Classic Form and specify in the beany head properties: Open XPage instead (there are 2 propeties: one for client one for browser). When you open a document with its classic URL it will open in XPage (?OpenDocument and ?EditDocument)
- Add a viewControl to an XPage (the same page or a different one) where you show the documents to select. In the viewControl specify your XPage to be used to open documents
- compute in what ever way you want the url to include documentID= which switches from new to display/edit mode (watch the URLs the view control is computing)
- Switch the form to "Existing document" and compute the docid (uniqueid) of the document as property. Could be a lookup a scopeVariable or whatever you deem fit.

Let us know how it goes. Check out the [XPages Cheatsheet](http://xpagescheatsheet.com/) for condensed information about all this.

Comment: This is very helpful (especially Xpages Cheatsheet). I have a view with employee documents, one per employee, the key of which is the user's common name. When a user goes to this page I want to present them their document in edit mode, and a dojo data grid with all documents, which they cannot open. The part I am having trouble with is how to bind the particular document to the Xpage automatically. Any suggestions would be very very appreciated?

Comment: you specify the UNID for the employee document. You can do a @DbLookup in a view with 2 columns. User name first @Text(@DocumentUniqueID)) in the second. Then use something like
@DbLookup(@DbName,"(LookupUserDoc)",@Name("[CN]",@UserName,2)); Feel free to accept the question

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much Simon. I was not aware of this place for errors. What I discovered was this:

```
Script interpreter error, line=6, col=5: 'doc' is null
     4: 
     5: var tmpOfficePhone = employee.getItemValueString("HR_OfficePhone")
->   6: doc.replaceItemValue("HR_OfficePhone",tmpOfficePhone);
     7: 
     8: var tmpCellPhone = employee.getItemValueString("HR_CellPhone")
```

The doc was null because I had a bad piece of code to get set the document. I had been using session.getCommonName but should have been using:

```
var usrNme = @Name("[CN]",session.getEffectiveUserName());
```

After replacing this line of code, everything worked. Thanks!!!

Comment: Is there a specific reason you go through all the code trouble instead of directly binding the fields to the document? Or any other binding option? Going after UI components makes your code very vulnerable to name changes

Comment: Because I don't know how. I would rather do that. How do I set up a data source that gets a particular document?

Comment: That would make a nice new question

Comment: OK I think I figured this out. I added a Domino Document as a datasource to a new page, set it to the form, and in the Document ID I put the following SSJS:                                    var usrNme = @Name("[CN]",session.getEffectiveUserName());
var v:NotesView = database.getView("(employeesByFullName)");
var doc:NotesDocument = v.getDocumentByKey(usrNme);
doc.getUniversalID()

Comment: Much faster: if (!sessionScope.userUNID) { sessionScope.userUNID =  
@DbLookup(@DbName,@Name("[CN]",@UserName,"(employeesByFullName)",2)} return sessionScope.userUNID; /* Does the lookup only once, needs the UNID in a view column */